# Preventing nix-env -i from installing $out/lib in the user-environment

Tags: nix, nixos

Is it possible to prevent the contents of `lib/` in a derivation from getting installed in the active `user-environment`? The package in question has an internal lib/   folder which should not be exposed to users, nor clutter the environment. As far as I have been able to discern, the links in `user-environment` are updated from within the nix-env binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. Instead of installing in $out, one can install in $out/pkg, and then create the appropriate links in $out. This prevents nix-env from finding `lib/` (amongst other things).